# How to search for plain text instead of a regular expression?

Tags: vim

For example, I want to delete untill the next `</p>` tag. Doing

```
d/</p>
```

Won't work since `</p>` is treated as a regular expression. Can I specify a plain text search pattern somehow?

Comment: This might be a reason to try Emacs: Ctrl-S !

Comment: with me it worked, but then I'm using easy-motion as default search, i don't know if that's it's working https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things that need to be changed for a literal search:

- The search delimiter (here: `/`) must be escaped with a backslash (`d/<\/p>`). If this were a pattern in a `:substitute` command, you could have also used a different delimiter (`:s#</p>##`), but for the `/` search command, you have to escape it.
- There are plenty of characters with special meaning in a regular expression. Instead of remembering and escaping them all, it's easier to change Vim's regular expression parsing to *very nomagic* mode via `\V`; then, only the backslash itself needs escaping. Your example pattern doesn't suffer from this, but it is relevant for characters like `.` and `*`.

Comment: You can use the _very nomagic_ mode in the following way: `/\V[foo]` to search for the literal string `[foo]` instead of the characters `f` or `o`.

Answer (score 2):

escape the slash with a backslash: `d/<\/p>`, although I am not sure if this will work, depending upon what the format of your file is.  You might have to do something more of the form `:.,/<\/p>/d`.